# How to set environment variable before running script inside hooks/install?

Tags: bash, php, juju

I am create a simple charm to get my symfony2 webapp from git and deploy it on ec2.

After getting the source from git, I want to run composer to resolve dependencies but I keep getting this error:

```
INFO juju context.go:221 worker/uniter: HOOK   The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly
```

I am running composer using below command inside my hooks/install script

```
juju-log "Running composer"
/usr/bin/php composer.phar install
```

I also tried

```
juju-log "Running composer"
COMPOSER_HOME=${app_dir};/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/php composer.phar install"
```

How can I set HOME or COMPOSER_HOME so that this command can be executed?

Comment: Please contact me (link in my profile page), I'd love to work with you on getting a symfony workflow in Ubuntu!

Comment: Sure @JorgeCastro, I will email you once my charm is complete.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`HOME` isn't set in the Juju hooks, only a few environment variables are.

You should be able to just run

```
COMPOSER_HOME="/path/you/want/to/be/home" php composer.phar install
```

which will set the environment variable before executing php.

Comment: Thanks Marco. That worked. 
I was trying similar but was giving ; before php, that should have also worked.
COMPOSER_HOME=${app_dir} ; /usr/bin/php composer.phar install

Comment: No, the `;` won't make COMPOSER_HOME an environment variable, just a variable, You would need `export COMPOSER_HOME=${app_dir};` the export makes it an environment variable. What I've done is just set it as an environment variable for _just_ that command.